# React: Howcome the sensitivity is messed up on my mobile slideshow only when using Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, carousel

I have a carousel component on my React web app. It works perfectly fine on Firefox, however in Chrome when I swipe down the page on mobile it thinks I'm doing a horizontal swipe and switches slides on my slideshow. I'm using a library called [react-material-ui-carouse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel), the only props it has available for sliding is to set the slide functionality to true or false. I couldn't find any mention of adjusting slide sensitivity in the docs. Is there a reasonable way for me to fix this or am I better off not using this library? [Link](https://exoticocharleston.com/) to the website if you want to try it out on mobile to see what I mean.

**Slideshow.jsx**

```
function Slideshow() {
  const fadeImages = [
    {
      src: "/images/allie-pic.webp",
      title: "First Slide",
      caption:
        "Slide1",
    },
    {
      src: "/images/image-2.jpg",
      title: "Second Slide",
      caption:
        "Slide2",
    },
    {
      src: "/images/image-3.webp",
      title: "Third Slide",
      caption:
        "Slide3",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Carousel
      swipe={true}
      autoPlay={false}
      fullHeightHover={false}  
     
    >
      {fadeImages.map((img, i) => (
        <Item key={i} img={img} />
      ))}
    </Carousel>
  );
}

function Item({ img }) {
  return (
    <Stack alignItems="center">
      <Typography variant="h1">
        {img.title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1">{img.caption}</Typography>
      <img     
        src={img.src}
      ></img>
    </Stack>
  );
}
export default Slideshow;
```